# DC.js - Adjusting the size of a stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I created a stacked bar chart using dc-js and I am trying to increase the size. However, every time I adjust the height attribute on the chart most of the chart is removed from view. My goal is to make viewing each of the stacks of the chart easier by enlarging the chart. Any information on how to do this, as well as why  the lower portion of the chart disappears upon adding the height attribute is very much appreciated!

Thank you in advance for any help.

[Chart before adjusting height.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scwx9.png) (referring to the area of care X acuity chart)

[Chart after adding/adjusting the height to 1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN7HL.png) (referring to the area of care X acuity chart)

**Javascript for "area of care x acuity chart" before adjusting height:**

```
aocChart
    .width(500)
    .margins({
        top: 5,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 75,
        left: 40
    })
    .dimension(aoc_dim)
    .group(sums.pop(), acuity_strings[0])
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticY(true);

var index = 1;
sums.forEach(function(sum) {
    aocChart.stack(sum, acuity_strings[index])
    index++;
});

aocChart
// .legend(dc.legend().x(500).y(0).itemHeight(12).gap(5).horizontal(1).legendWidth(90).itemWidth(95))
    .render();
```

**Javascript for "area of care x acuity chart after adjusting height:**

```
aocChart
    .width(500)
    .height(1000)
    .margins({
        top: 5,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 75,
        left: 40
    })
    .dimension(aoc_dim)
    .group(sums.pop(), acuity_strings[0])
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticY(true);

var index = 1;
sums.forEach(function(sum) {
    aocChart.stack(sum, acuity_strings[index])
    index++;
});

aocChart
// .legend(dc.legend().x(500).y(0).itemHeight(12).gap(5).horizontal(1).legendWidth(90).itemWidth(95))
    .render();
```

Comment: Are you adjusting the height after the initial render? dc.js is not very smart about resizing so you currently have to call `rescale` when changing the size. Otherwise, if this is all in one go, I'm surprised it doesn't work. If you can post a fiddle we can help troubleshoot better.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Gordon! Nope I am not adjusting the height after the initial render. In my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kdasu/7Lpf21yw/6/ it seems to work as expected.   I believe the issue may be related to the fact I am using **meteor** to develop?

Comment: Could be! Does that do the layout for you? I guess I'd next start poking around with the Inspector in your favorite browser's dev tools, to find out which element is the wrong size. The DOM is a complicated beast...

Comment: So after using the inspector I think I found a clue to the issue shown better in this screenshot http://imgur.com/mAlBpCj.  I set the barchart .height(1000) and the .width(500) in the inspector view for the svg it has the correct values in the tag. However while my mouse is over the svg the box over the chart says the dims are 696.08 x 200.

Comment: Found the issue! It was CSS related, the default svg css had height fixed at 200px. Adding svg { height: 100%; width: 100%; }  to my css file solved my problem.

Comment: Ah yes, style trumps css trumps attributes. It's a beautiful world we live in. Glad you figured it out!